# Angular 5 using something else than <base href="/"> as path reference

Tags: angular

I'm building an Angular 5 app, Angular core and ngx-translate are using `<base href="/">` as path reference (to get assets such as translations files or pictures).
In production my Angular app can be included in any website as a module/plugin, it can be a WordPress, Joomla, static HTML website... So there's maybe already a `<base href="/">` that I can't change. So can I set Angular and ngx-translate path to assets with another system, how would you avoid conflict?

Comment: Are you using angular-cli?

Comment: yes I'm using CLI to build the project and to generate almost everything

Comment: Can you use --deploy-url setting instead of changing base href?

Comment: But --deploy-url takes a fixed value at compilation right? I can't dynamically change it in the HTML such as the base href value? I need to change it dynamically in the code. Thanks